# XAMPP + WAMP very slow over the weekend?

Tags: windows, apache2, xampp, wamp

I use xampp for half a year now, with xdebug and some other extensions. Everything is fine but now, over the weekend it magically went horrible slow. Does not matter if i enter "localhost", "127.0.0.1" or my LAN-IP.

So i installed WAMP. As i know now, WAMP for x64 is a waste of time - (CURL not working) so i installed WAMP x32.

CURL is working so far but the page still takes over a minute to load! Not building the page, not processing the code, to me it looks hardly like it takes a minute to start processing.

Sadly, can anyone recommend a fully working php-apache-mysql bundle for windows that is working as expected with all provided extensions in 2014?? Would be nice if that package/software (if it exists) would work as expected without need to modify registry, systemfiles, dll's and without spending hours and hours to get a simple page-request working.

Last but not least, the content of my host-file:

```
#::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1
```

I tried really everything i found on the web so far. Nothing helps. Theres a similar question to this on Stackoverflow - without any useful (fixing) answer.

**Collective Information:**

- XAMPP and WAMPP are slow
- localhost/127.0.0.1/LAN-IP in URL does not
  affect performance
- the webserver does not take long to perform
  requests
- the websever does need about 60 seconds to recieve a request
- cross-browser tested
- with killed session tested

Comment: Actually you can download a fixed curl extension for the 64bit PHP  from here http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

Comment: Though its not affecting my mistake - i tried the fixed curl-DLL without any success. I dont get why they still share setup-bundles for x64 machines without something essential like curl. Any ideas about my performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try removing the line

```
127.0.0.1  127.0.0.1
```

from your HOSTS file.

It is an illegal instruction anyway, but I have know it to cause loops. Does you PHP error file or Apache error file tell you anything useful?

Was this something you added, just before the system slowed down?

**ADDITIONAL SUGGESTION:**

Also changing these settings has been known to help on Windows systems, you may need to add then to your httpd.conf if they dont already exist.

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Comment: Dropping the line does not result in any changes. The Error-Logs are empty about the issue. I cant tell, on friday everything was ok. I am also running on an SSD so i can leave out my hardware.

Comment: Have a look at the Windows Event Log. In the Windows -> Applications section for messages from Apache

Comment: Wondering whether you are wrong or this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6165424/3048505

Comment: @xcy7e Its probably me, but I cannot see how creating a cirular reference to 127.0.0.1 would be a good idea! Bu tI am always eager to learn.

Answer (score 0):

1. In wamp php.ini turn off displaying errors and change type of displaying errors! :)

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
```

[enter php.ini via wamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRZH5.png)
[edit these lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8wpQ.png)

2. Enable gzip
   a) enable apache modules: deflate_module and headers_module
   b) than paste code below to ur main wordpress folder .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```